VSCode Remote-SSH automation of connection using tasks
I want to make a task, which helps me to connect to my remote development server via Remote-SSH extension. Though I was able to successfully call the command palette for picking a server to connect, I couldn't figure out how to automatically pick a server for connection.
Here is my file with tasks
tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "remote",
            "command": "${command:opensshremotes.openEmptyWindow}",
            "problemMatcher": [],
        },
    ]
}

Is there any way to write text directly to command palette from the task interface? Or, maybe, there is another way to pick option from command palette automatically?
I tried to use "args" field, but it seems like it doesn't really affect my task at all.
